# How to cast a []byte with a pointer of struct?

Tags: go

I'd like to use Go for low level project and avoid copying data.

I have a struct of fixed size:

```
type myStruct struct {
    a    uint8
    b    uint8
}
```

I would like to cast a `pointer of my struct` with this `slice of bytes` in order to read the value as if the slice of bytes was a struct without copying anything.

```
data := []byte{69,0}

var obj *myStruct

//something like:
obj = myStruct(data)
// or
obj = &myStruct(data)
```

In C it would be: `obj = (struct myStruct*) data;`

- **Is it possible ? What are the solutions to do so ? The best practice ?**

*I'd like to void using offset and index for the []byte.*

*Since a slice is not a fixed memory, I guess it'd be possible by converting `[]byte` into a fixed array `byte[0:2]`.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast `unsafe.Pointer` to `*myStruct` passing pointer to the first element of the bytes slice:

```
import "unsafe"
...
obj = (*myStruct)(unsafe.Pointer(&data[0]))
```

test: https://play.golang.org/p/c7XO3dPKcLu

Comment: No other Go-native solution ? Is this solution working with any []byte's length ? Since slice's memory map isn't contiguous, I wonder how unsafe package can handle it without altering performance by copying or... will check with benchmark.

Comment: @Alexis_FR_JP, This is Go native, and a slice is always contiguous.

Comment: Great, I avoided using `unsafe` because of the name and because I heard Rob Pike saying we shouldn't go in production with an app that imports `unsafe`. Need to focus more on it then. Thank you!

Comment: Don't do that. Just don't. In *this* case (`uint8` fields) I cannot imagine a case where it will fail, but for more complicated cases, it will fail—say, due to strict alignment rules you won't be able to "cast" a byte slice to something like `type t struct { a int32; b byte; c int32 }` as the compiler will pad `b` with 3 bytes so that `c` ends up at an address which is evenly divisible by 4. There are also endianness issues—what if your program tested on a little-endian machine tomorrow will read the same data on a big-endian machine?

Comment: Consider reading [this](https://dave.cheney.net/2015/10/09/padding-is-hard) and [this](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/25/the-empty-struct) for a start.

Comment: The proper approach is to use the `encoding/binary` package to explicitly read your data from the slice to the struct fields.

Comment: Happy New Year! The purpose of this is to send a pointer of a struct to a combined/PCIe driver (connected to a FPGA). I used to add the alignment/padding by myself in the structure by adding dummy field to align to 4B, I don't use 64b values.

Comment: I will focus more on `encoding/binary` library, I focused on Go rather than Nodejs for the low-level ability, hope I wont be disappointed.
Thanks for your replies !